# Android running emulator

Tags: android

When I run my android project it isn't running in emulator but it is showing in the android studio. Moreover, in messages, it is showing a message "Build Project failed", "Can't connect to the ADB Server" and some other errors. Even if I run simple Hello World project I'm getting same errors. What should I do to run my project in an emulator? I'm running nexus 5 with android 5.1.

Comment: That is because your build.gradle is failing. Can you post that file?

Comment: Do you want me to post the project or error messages?

Comment: The file and the errors you get because we can't help you if you don't submit those 2 things.

Comment: Can you start the emulator? Please also add your **build.gradle** files as well as the full text of the errors you get.

Comment: yes, I can run the emulator but not the project..

Comment: When I try to run the same in my mobile via USB debugging I get errors like"Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0,  Information:BUILD FAILED"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem too. But we have to look error messages. In general solution;

- You just create the AVD with 768 MB RAM (*It was worked*).
- Just use **Genymotion** (*more fast and reliable. Now i'm using this*).

Comment: What is "Genymotion"? I'm a beginner and I'm learning it through youtube tutorials..

Comment: Genymotion is another android emulator. To install and using it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWZ2rVFOQWw

Comment: Thank you:) and I also i can't build apk same error i'm getting as said above.Can you help me

Comment: In Android Studio: Build -> Rebuild Project.